# Wrong cumulative count for dimension level

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, mdx

I have a dimension hierarchy like this:  Year -> Month Name -> Date.

I'm trying to get a cumulative count of items, so I created a calculated measure using this expression:

```
SUM(null:[Dim Date].[Hierarchy], [Measures].[ParentCount])
```

It works great for the year level, but I don't understand why i'm getting wrong value for Month and Date.

I've post an image resuming the problem (Sorry I can't include it on the post because i'm a new user on stackoverflow)

[image]

Like I said, the count for the Year Level is good. What's wrong with the other one? SSAS/MDX is new to me.. I guess something is missing in my calculated measure, or maybe it's my hierarchy ..

Thanks!

Comment: Your hierarchy is also completely unecessary since there are functions for determining month/year from a date field...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what you're looking for, but try :

```
SUM(null:[Dim Date].[Hierarchy].currentmember, [Measures].[ParentCount])
```

To get an idea what this function is doing try :

```
count(null:[Dim Date].[Hierarchy].currentmember)
```

and even better using the [SetToStr MDX function](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/SetToStr.html)

```
SetToStr(null:[Dim Date].[Hierarchy].currentmember)
```

But, actually an [MDX Debugger](http://www.iccube.com/products/iccube/mdx-ide), sorry not for SSAS, would help you understanding what is going on  :-)